# Setting Focus Order (Webworks)

Tags: jquery, html, blackberry-webworks

My app focus order seems to be out of order. The app is supposed to retrieve a listing of records from webservices and then being display using a for loop in a div.

Example:

```
function loadListing()
{
  var listing = "";
  var value = new Array('One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five', 'Six', 'Seven', 'Eight', 
  'Nine', 'Ten');

  listing += '<div style="background-color: purple; color: yellow; padding: 10px;  
  margin-bottom: 10px;">I\'m some big listing</div>';

  listing += '<div id="container">';

  for(var h = 0; h < 10; h++)
  {
    listing += '<div class="innerContainer" x-blackberry-focusable="true" 
    onmouseover="bigHover(this)" onmouseout="dontHover(this)">';
    listing += '<div style="font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold;">'+value[h]+'</div>'; 
    listing += '</div>';
  }
  listing += '</div>';

  listing += '<div style="background-color: purple; color: yellow; padding: 10px;   
  margin-top: 20px;margin-bottom: 10px;">I\'m self-generate listing</div>';
  for(var i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
  {
    listing += '<div><ul class="ulClass">';
    listing += '<li><span class="pretty" x-blackberry-focusable="true"   
    onmouseover="hoverMe(this)" onmouseout="dontHover(this)">' +i+' </span></li>';
    listing += '</ul></div>';
  }
 $('#mainBody').html(listing);
}
```

CSS:

```
.ulClass{ list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }

.ulClass li{ display: inline; float: left; }

.pretty{ font-size: 20px; color: orange; border: 1px solid orange; padding: 3px; 
         margin: 3px; width: 5px; }
```

When user has finish scrolling on the listing the next focusable element on the paging(ul class="paging") will be on page 10 instead of page 1.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ZAw8v/)

Can anyone please help?

Comment: What is expected to happen here?

Comment: When user scroll down the listing(the one with One, Two etc) once they reach the last listing(Ten) when they move their trackpad the focus should be on "1" in ulClass and not "10" paging list. But it goes straight to "10".

Comment: did u check the fiddle I created? Is this behaviour present there?

Comment: Yes, I tried it on the BB device. It still goes to the last page number.